# wordpress footer.php will not appear in single.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My footer.php file will pull into every page except the single.php, I have no idea why this is occurring! Any ideas?

Below is the Single.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="small-banner">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <img src="http://www.quorngrangehotel.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/new-events-banner.jpg">
        </div>

<main role="main" class="mainContent">

        <div id="inner-content" class="row">

            <main id="main" class="large-8 medium-8 columns" role="main">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'single' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>                     

            </main> <!-- end #main -->

        </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->

</main><!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What happens if you inspect the page when viewing from browser? Where does it end/happens?

Comment: I found out the issue it was something to do with the comments section being pulled in via the single template part!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the issue it was something to do with the comments section being pulled in via the single template part!

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the original question.

Comment: It was a comment as well but I was removing it from my unanswered list.

Comment: It might be wise to give a more detailed answer then.